# Woocommerce Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a 'Sold Date' attribute to single 'one-off' items - this is so customers can see whats been selling in the past (basically when a product sells, I go in the back-end and add the Month/Year to this attribute)

These are collectable items - so only one can be bought!

**What I would like to do is 'hide the cart' on a product that has this 'Sold Date' attribute only.**

I've also a 'Reserved By' attribute as well where I'd like to do the same!

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You could also set the stock status to out of stock and update the message. Just an idea/alternate way.

Comment: Of course.....thats actually a much better way......not new to wordpress, but I am to woocommerce! Cheers Chris

Comment: I've changed 'Out of Stock' to 'Sold' which is better for this shop.....is there anyway to add the month and year to this?

Comment: There is no way to add the Month and Date, but a developer can take it from the order records. Also, you can make this "out of stock" automatically by setting the stock to "1" for all the items, so once it is being purchased it will be automatically "out of stock" and you won't need to update each one.

Comment: Thanks - I've poured over a few questions regarding showing a possible 'date sold'.....I've found a work around by creating an attribute called 'Sold' and adding months and years, so when a product is sold - i can manually add this attribute and it displays fine on the single product page and shop page.....not ideal, but hey ho! Yeah - I did think about possibly hard coding something to be associate the order records - but thats a pain :-(

Comment: If anyone's interested in what I mean! http://diecastgems.net/sold-models/